# Backup content of external hard drive using Windows 8 File History

Tags: windows-8, file-history

I would like to backup drives connected with USB to my Windows 8 system, using the new File History function. I have tried to add the drive to a library (*Pictures*) but that did not work. Does anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: You don't need to add the drive to your library to back it up.

Comment: So, how do I tell Windows 8 to back it up then please?